# react router v3 onEnter wait for promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I looked everywhere before posting this question, but I couldn't find anything!!!

So I want that some routes in my react app wait for a Promise to be resolved so I can check the users-roles if that user can access a particular route.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work !

```
 checkRoles = (nextState, replace) => {

    if(token && !loggedUser) {
            this.getUserData()
            .then(() => {
              alert('you are logged in.');
              replace('/dashboard');
            })
            .catch(() => {
              alert('session expired.');
              replace('/login');
            });
          } else {
            alert('Please login first.');
            replace('frontend/login');
          }
      }
```

The replace is totally ignored in `catch` and `then` functions, I also tried passing a third arg `callback()`, it doesn't work as well!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 3rd parameter of the onEnter function:

```js
checkRoles = (nextState, replace, cb) => {
  if (token && !loggedUser) {
    this.getUserData()
      .then(() => {
        alert('you are logged in.');
        replace('/dashboard');
        cb();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('session expired.');
        replace('/login');
        cb();
      });
  } else {
    alert('Please login first.');
    replace('frontend/login');
    cb();
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry man, I already said that I tried that but it doesn't work. The alert pops up but the replace is still ignored